# Memory leakage due to presumably unclosed kernels

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm forced to work with JupyterLab on a Linux-server which I do not host myself.
The problem is that the Jupyter-process takes a lot of memory; this has been part in several bug reports like [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/642) and [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8267).

Anyhow, as can be anticipated from the introduction, I do not have any sudo-rights and therefore cannot restart the lab myself (at least I think that this should not be possible for me).

Whats odd in my opinion can be seen on this Screenshot taken from HTOP:

[image: JupyterLab]

The bash command which startet the lab has a lot of subprocesses which all look like kernels I opened and closed over the entire usage-time (the server is up for a month and I opened and closed a lot of kernels; none was running when taking the picture).

Since every of these processes ends on `.json`, I assume that these might be some still intact runtime parameters. All processes on the third level look identical like on the screenshot, nothing else there.

Anyhow, I don't want to resolve the memory-spilling-bug. My question is rather straight forward:

***Since no kernel is running: Can I just kill all of the processes on the third level and free the memory by doing so, or might this crash the lab?***
Not crashing the lab is essential since I have no possibility to restart the lab.

Comment: did you ever find the root cause of this and a solution - rather than a killer workaround?

Comment: @jtlz2: Unfortunately not. I have to admit that I just accepted the workaround and some time later contacted the admin for a restart of the system which also helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily, I stumbled upon this website [here](http://thoughtsondl.blogspot.com/2018/06/how-to-release-or-reset-gpu-memory-in.html).
Here the writer has a related problem with unreleased GPU-memory and also a lot of `ipykernel_launchers`.

He solved this problem by using the proposed drastic way.

1. First, display all your `ipykernel_launchers` with `ps -aux|grep ipykernel_launcher` (analog to the HTOP-screenshot in the question).
2. Kill every process one by one with `kill -9 PID1 PID2 ...`. Be sure to **only** kill everything in the style of (nothing else):

   > /usr/bin/python3 -m ipykernel_launcher -f /content/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-95cb65b9-23eb-4f87-801b-d995ca30fc32.json
3. Memory should be freed now and JupyterLab should be still running.

---

***Edit:***

Thanks to @EightBitTony [on Unix&Linux-StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50573/358881) I now know that there is a command to kill all processes in one step:

```
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep -v "awk" | awk '/ipykernel_launcher/ {print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done
```

Please be aware what you do when you do it this way!

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a built in way to kill processes given a certain pattern:

```
pkill -f /<regex-pattern>/
```

In your case, `pkill -f ".*/ipykernel_launcher/.*"` would do the trick